# imagejpeg - failed to open stream

Tags: php

I use function resizeImage() to resize images but **occasionally** fails. Most time it is working but I have sometime this warnings that it can't find file. What should be the problem ? How to fix that problem ?

Ideas:

1. <del>Permissions to file</del>
2. Bad path of image
3. <del>Sessions</del>
4. <del>Permissions to write to dir</del>

Usage:

```
<?php

session_start();

define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT_DIR', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . DS);

$image = ROOT_DIR . 'cache' . DS . $_SESSION['file_name'];
resizeImage($image, 400, 400);
```

Throws **error:**

```
Warning: imagejpeg(C:\wamp\www\mvc\cache\temp_1385972631.jpg): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\wamp\www\mvc\application\helpers\image_helper.php on line 95
```

Line #95: `imagejpeg($newImage, $image, 100);`

Here is **resizeImage()** function:

```
<?php

function resizeImage($image, $max_width, $max_height) {

    $img = getimagesize($image);

    $mime = $img['mime'];
    $width = $img[0];
    $height = $img[1];

    if ($height > $width) {
        $scale = $max_height / $height;
    }
    elseif ($width > $height) {
        $scale = $max_width / $width;
    }
    else {
        $scale = 1;
    }

    $newImageWidth = ceil($width * $scale);
    $newImageHeight = ceil($height * $scale);
    $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newImageWidth, $newImageHeight);
    imagealphablending($newImage, false);
    imagesavealpha($newImage, true);
    switch ($mime) {
        case "image/gif":
            $source = imagecreatefromgif($image);
            break;
        case "image/pjpeg":
        case "image/jpeg":
        case "image/jpg":
            $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
            break;
        case "image/png":
        case "image/x-png":
            $source = imagecreatefrompng($image);
            break;
    }
    imagecopyresampled($newImage, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newImageWidth, $newImageHeight, $width, $height);

    switch ($mime) {
        case "image/gif":
            imagegif($newImage, $image);
            break;
        case "image/pjpeg":
        case "image/jpeg":
        case "image/jpg":
            imagejpeg($newImage, $image, 100); // line #95
            break;
        case "image/png":
        case "image/x-png":
            imagepng($newImage, $image);
            break;
    }

    chmod($image, 0777);
    return $image;
}
```

**Edit:**
added var_dump before imagejpeg($newImage, $image, 100); // line #102

```
//var_dump($newImage);
resource(18) of type (gd)

//var_dump($image);
string(41) "C:\wamp\www\mvc\cache\temp_1385978306.jpg"

Warning: imagejpeg(C:\wamp\www\mvc\cache\temp_1385978306.jpg): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\wamp\www\mvc\application\helpers\image_helper.php on line 102
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the error? Does it only happen with .jpg files? Also please try a var_dump for $newImage and $image just before the imagejpeg call and post the results here.

Comment: Are you trying to overwrite the original image with this new image? Can you try writing to a separate directory?

Comment: @Patrick I am trying to reproduce error, but no luck yet. I added var_dumps to dev version, so when error occurs I will post results.

Comment: @DannyHearnah If string `$image` is given and it exists, it will be overwritten by default, so that is not issue.

Comment: @Patrick I reproduced error, edited question -> added outputs

Answer (score 3):

i had the same problem.
it might be because you did not create folder that named 'cache'.
(it seems that GD does not create directories and assumes that directory is created before and has required privileges(e.g 0777) .)

Comment: 775 would be recommended as this is a server-side function and 777 puts it open for anybody